# Python Histogram

Tags: python, python-3.x, histogram

I'm trying to create a histogram in python as a part of my `python` class

It is supposed to look like this:

[image]

However, I can't figure out the histogram. This is my code so far:

```
sumValues = [] 

print("Enter 10 integers")

for i in range( 10 ):
    newValue = int( input("Enter integer %d: " % (i + 1) ))
    sumValues.append(newValue)

print("\nCreating a histogram from values: ")
print("%s %10s %10s" %("Element", "Value", "Histogram"))
```

How do I create the actual histogram?

Comment: What you have displayed is not, properly speaking, a 'histogram' (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram for instance).  However, that does not change the answers as to how to print what your displayed.

Answer (score 2):

Some hints:
New-style Python formatting allows this:

```
In [1]: stars = '*' * 4    # '****'
In [2]: '{:<10s}'.format(stars)
Out[3]: '****      '
```

That is, you can take a string of 4 stars (formed by repetition of `'*'` four times) and place it in a string of length 10 characters, aligned to the left (`<`) and padded to the right with whitespace.

(If you don't need the histogram to have the same number of characters (stars or spaces), just print the stars; no need to format)

Answer (score 0):

Just like this:

```
# fake data
sumValues = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
...
# calculate how long is the list and adjust the padding for 'Element'
padding = max(len(sumValues), len('Element'))
# now the padding for 'Value'
padding1 = max(len(str(max(sumValues))), len('Value')) 

print("\nCreating a histogram from values: ")
print("%s %10s %10s" %("Element", "Value", "Histogram"))
# use enumerate to loop your list and giving the index started from 1
for i,n in enumerate(sumValues, start=1):
    print '{0} {1}     {2}'.format( # print each line with its elements
              str(i).ljust(padding), # print with space using str.ljust
              str(i).rjust(padding1), # print with space using str.rjust
              '*'*n) # '*' * n = '*' multiply by 'n' times 

Creating a histogram from values: 
Element      Value  Histogram
1              1     *
2              2     **
3              3     ***
4              4     ****
5              5     *****
6              6     ******
7              7     *******
8              8     ********
9              9     *********
10            10     **********
```